# Is it possible to get code-completionon all methods and classes in a project?

Tags: php, netbeans

I have a project which is some kind of MVC pattern. In the boot class I make instance of the controller which make instance of view and model. But model is loaded with a method loadModel. Then all controllers extend the controller class. It is like this:

```
class boot{
  function __construct(){
    //some code... exploding url etc
    require 'controllers/'.$url[0].".php";
    $this->controller = new $url[0];
    $this->controller->loadModel($url[0]);
    //.....
  }
}

class controller{
  function __construct(){
    $this->view = new view();
  }
  function loadModel($name){
    $modelName = $name."_model"
    //....
    $this->model = new $modelName();
    //....
  }
}

class model{
    // some code
}

class view{
    // some code
}
```

So I make new controller and model:

```
class test_model extends model{
    function __construct(){
       parent::__construct()
    }

    function alabala(){
       some code...
    }
    function afdfa(){
       some code...
    }
    function asdfadf(){
       some code...
    }
}

class test extends controller{
   function __construct(){
      parent::__construct()
   }

   ->here is the problem<-
   $this->model->no methods suggestions
}
```

NetBeans does not suggest any method from `test_model`.

PhpDesigner 7 and PhpDesigner 8 suggest all methods form any model class. How can I set NetBeans to offer me all methods from all clasess in the project?

Comment: This may help, it is specifically for Zend Framework, but may be of use to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9307782/how-to-set-up-netbeans-autocomplete-with-zend-framework/9309393#9309393

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your IDE will go only so far in working out the type of your attribute. There are two ways to solve it:

```
class boot {
    /* @var $model test_model */
    protected $model;

    ....
}
```

Thinking about it, that might be just `/* $var test_model */`; I'm not sure, since I always use a custom getter:

```
class test extends controller {

   public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct()
   }

   public function anotherMethod() {
       $this->getTestMode->will offer model suggestions...
   }

   /**
    * Get test_model
    *
    * @return test_model
    */
   public function getTestModel() {
       return $this->model;
   }
}
```

It's the "phpdoc" comments that notify your IDE as to the type of class returned, which auto-selects the correct set of class methods and attributes to offer.

Aside: it's a good style to *always* specify your access level, i.e. whether your methods and attributes are `public`, `protected` or `private`. True, they are `public` by default, but without this specifier they rather look like legacy PHP4, and new style guides (e.g. PSR-x) are embracing the explicit form.